# Opacity control based on front/back arrangement

Tags: transparency

I would like to have a long, thin object that zig-zags across the surface. Thin object would go behind another object at one location, and then in front of another object at another location. "Behind" and "in front" is relative to the camera view.

I was wondering if I could control the opacity of the thin object based on whether it's behind another object or not. The other two objects are semi-transparent (Principled BSDF alpha control), so I would like to reduce the opacity of the thin object when it's behind the other object.

I hope it's not an issue if I don't provide a model because I don't have any idea on where to start with the shaders, etc. I'd appreciate any info or guidance.